# django-pytest xunit style access database issue

Tags: django, database, unit-testing, pytest, xunit

I start to test my Django project recently. At first, I test my code by accessing my local full data DB, but it seems like not a proper way.

So , I try to create fake data in local migrated database without real data.

And pytest provide xunit style , so setup_module or setup_class .... become my insert fake data entry point.

Also , I add below code to conftest.py avoid insert @pytest.mark.django_db everywhere

`@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def enable_db_access_for_all_tests(db):
    pass`

But, I still get error message, when I create fake data in setup_module or 
setup_class.

`def setup_module():
    print('setup_module....')
    HostSite.objects.create(prefix='us', vhost='www', enable_site=True, locale='en_us')`

Error Message:

`Failed: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.`

Could anyone help me to figure out what I miss? please.

Comment: `use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it` isn't this helpful?

Comment: @KishorPawar No, I did it. But it still throw exception.

Comment: Show me your databse  settings from settings.py

Comment: Have you done this configuration? `# -- FILE: pytest.ini (or tox.ini)
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = test_settings`

Comment: @KishorPawar  ```platform darwin -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-3.5.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0 -- 
metadata: {'Python': '3.5.2', 'Plugins': {'xdist': '1.22.2', 'cov': '2.5.1', 'mock': '1.10.0', 'metadata': '1.7.0', 'celery': '4.1.0', 'html': '1.17.0', 'django': '3.2.1', 'forked': '0.2'}, 'Packages': {'pytest': '3.5.1', 'pluggy': '0.6.0', 'py': '1.5.3'}, 'Platform': 'Darwin-17.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit'}
Django settings: local_settings (from ini file)```    I am sure that config file is set, and create object in  xunit style  would throw exception.

Comment: my local db setting```DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME', 'abc_db'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER', 'aircon'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_SECRET', 'test1234'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'test_abc_db',
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Can you please print these settings so that you can see what settings exactly being used.

Comment: `setup_module` is not a fixture, so `enable_db_access_for_all_tests` is not applied to it. Consider refactoring old-style `setup_module` to a fixture with the module scope. Also, as stated in `pytest` docs: _While these setup/teardown methods are simple and familiar to those coming from a unittest or nose background, you may also consider using pytest’s more powerful fixture mechanism._